# AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(obj asset) наоборот

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
string s = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(obj asset);
```

Так я получу путь до файла, который передам в аргумент. А как наоборот, получить объект ассета, указав путь до него? Ну как то вроде того

```
object o = AssetDatabase.GetAssetFromPath(str patch);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, вам стоит посмотреть в сторону этих методов

- [AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath.html)
- [AssetDatabase.LoadMainAssetAtPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadMainAssetAtPath.html)
- [AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath.html)

В особенности, если вы не знаете тип или не хотите его указывать, посмотрите в сторону последнего метода. Если у вас есть полный путь до объекта (включая его название) и это простой объект (смотрите пример в документации), то получите массив из одного искомого объекта. А в силу того, что речь идет о скриптах для редактора, накладными расходами в виде массивов можно пренебречь.